# Where is "JVM and Java Settings" CF Admin Page in Adobe ColdFusion 9

Tags: java, coldfusion, classpath

Many guides refer to the "JVM and Java Settings" page (in the CF Admin) to manipulate the classpath in Adobe ColdFusion. (I happen to be on ACF9.)

I'm running Multi-Server ACF9 on Linux (Ubuntu), but I can't find that page anywhere.

[image: CF Admin]

Where is it, and/or how do I manipulate the CF classpath? (In particular, I'd like to modify it for one specific instance.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

“JVM and Java Settings” is only available for single server install.

update `jvm.config` in CF9 Multiserver: `<jrun_root>\bin\`

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/change-coldfusion-jvm.html

By default they all share one `jvm.config`.  You may use a custom `jvm.config` per instance, see: http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/6/26/identifying_what_instance_uses_a_given_jvm_config

Comment: I've tried using a per-instance jvm.config, but I haven't found guidance on *precisely* how to properly add something to it. (See the end of my OP.) Any idea?

(Should I split that out into a separate question?)

Comment: Maybe you should.  Post what you have done so far, and post the flex errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505738/adding-to-coldfusion-classpath-for-particular-instance-in-multi-server-adobe-col